# Reading data from a network keeping in the folder structure which is specified in CSV

Tags: windows, csv, batch-file

While trying to Copy from the network path by using batch file I am Getting invalid number of parameters. I don't know whats the mistake.

```
SET InputFile=D:\backup\DatabasesName.csv
SET letest=network Path
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%B IN ('type "%InputFile%"') DO SET %%C=%%B
SET skipfile=D:\backup
xcopy /r /d /i /s /c /y /e /exclude:%skipfile%\excludedfileslist.txt %letest%\*.* %LETEST%
```

The bellow is the Actual Code for which I am Getting I am Getting invalid number of parameters

```
set/p pass="%pass%"
SET InputFile=D:\backup\DatabasesName.csv
SET ui=\\tfs-server\TFSBUILDS\OB-MAINMVC2.0\OB-MAINMVC2.0_%pass%\_PublishedWebsites\in-mvc-20
SET auth=\\tfs-server\TFSBUILDS\OB-MAINMVC2.0\OB-MAINMVC2.0_%pass%\_PublishedWebsites        \In.OfficeBox.Api.Auth
SET inventory=\\tfs-server\TFSBUILDS\OB-MAINMVC2.0\OB-MAINMVC2.0_%pass%\_PublishedWebsites        \In.OfficeBox.Api.Inventory
FOR /F "tokens=2,3 delims=," %%B IN ('type "%InputFile%"') DO SET %%C=%%B
SET skipfile=D:\backup
xcopy /r /d d-m-y /i /s /c /y /e /exclude:%skipfile%\excludedfileslist.txt %ui%\*.* %UISITE%
xcopy /r /d d-m-y /i /s /c /y /e /exclude:%skipfile%\excludedfileslist.txt %auth%\*.* %AUTHSITE%
xcopy /r /d d-m-y /i /s /c /y /e /exclude:%skipfile%\excludedfileslist.txt %inventory%\*.*
```

Comment: Can you show us the content of `DatabaseName.csv`?

Comment: the `/d` flag requires date with a format of m-d-y

Comment: And maybe you should try: `xcopy %letest%\*.* %LETEST% /r /d d-m-y /i /s /c /y /e /exclude:%skipfile%\excludedfileslist.txt`?

Comment: BTW, paths require quoting, like `"%letest\*.*%"`

Comment: Path     | Nxt

D:path | LETEST

Comment: Please put it in your post, and I don't see why you use `,` as delims.

Comment: Then what delims should I Specify

Comment: What separates the information, in this case, `^|`, the `^` is added on purposely to fix this escape issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in the script.

---

## Incorrect `DELIMS`

It seemed that you need `|` to separate the information. But you can't just put `delims=|`, since `|` has it's special use. Instead, use `delims=^|`.

## `XCOPY /D` Flag

According to `xcopy /?`, one need to specific year, month and date using such format:

```
/d d-m-y
```

## File Path Quoting

Consider this:

```
xcopy Folder With Space\a.txt Folder With Space\b.txt
```

Command prompt sees:

`xcopy Folder With (and a whole bunch of unknown arguments)`

To prevent `cmd` doing so, add quotes like so:

```
xcopy "%letest%\*.*" "%letest%"
```

## Possible Typo

Do you mean `Latest` instead of`Letest`?

Comment: Thanks This Worked for me I had to Quotes.